# Converting an INNER JOIN query from SQLite to SQLite.Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I started this app using LiveCode and SQLite and I've since switched over to Xcode and SQLit.Swift. I'm using an existing database. I'm having a little trouble converting an inner join of some of the tables.

Right now I'm dealing with 3 tables:
CrossRef, My_Data and My_Routines

My_Data contains DataID and Data_Name and My_Routines contain RoutineID and Routine_Name.

The CrossRef table was created like this. It only has 2 fields, DataID and RoutineID

```
CREATE TABLE "CrossRef" ("DataID INTEGER NOT NULL, "RoutineID" INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY("RoutineID") REFERENCES "My_Routines", PRIMARY KEY("DataID","RoutineID"), FOREIGN KEY("DataID") REFERENCES "My_Data"
```

**I'm trying to re-wright the following line so I can use it with SQLite.Swift and I could really use some help. I've included the Expressions for the table and the fields.**

```
let crossRefTable = Table("CrossRef")
let crossRefRoutineID = Expression<Int64>("RoutineID")
let crossRefDataID = Expression<Int64>("DataID")

let theDataTable = Table("My_Data")
let dataID = Expression<Int64>("DataID")
let data_Name = Expression<String>("Data_Name")

let theRoutineTable = Table("My_Routines")
let routineID = Expression<Int64>("RoutineID")

SELECT My_Data.Data_Name FROM CrossRef INNER JOIN My_Data USING (DataID) WHERE CrossRef.RoutineID = gRoutineID
```

I've read through the SQLite.Swift documentation online but I'm afraid it's not helping me much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with. Just in case anybody has the same problem.

```
let theQuery = crossRefTable.join(.inner, theDataTable, on: crossRefDataID == dataID) .filter(crossRefRoutineID == gRoutineID)
```